# "Connection reset by peer" in camel-based app when producer close the connection

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

We use the camel framework and the Netty client. 
 The application sends a request to a producer with header connection: keep-alive.
We get OK response(code: 200) and everything looks ok. But a couple of minutes later the producer close the connection (with a tcp RST). That causes an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1108)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:563)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In the log file we could also see following warning:
`Cannot determine current route from Exchange with id: XXX-1573787037638-0-2421168, will fallback and use first error handler.`

We found that this warning is logged in `org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler` because `uow == null` but the code also contains the comment:

```
// note this should really not happen, but we have this code as a fail safe 
// to be backwards compatible with the old behavior
```

Since this exception is caught by the application exception handler, this causes a lot of confusion and to temporarily solve this, we made an override of SimpleChannelInboundHandler.exceptionCaught.

```
// signal callback
  if(exchange.getUnitOfWork() == null){
    LOG.warn("Exception without UnitOfWork, this is not propagated to Camel", cause);
} else {
    callback.done(false);
}
```

Our solution is to only do a callback if there is a UnitOfWork available. But we are not sure this is the correct way to do it or if this solution could cause other problems. 
Any suggestions for solve problem?

UPD. Rout:

```
 from(DIRECT_PRODUCER_ROUTE)
            .routeId(TO_PRODUCER_ROUTE)

            .onException(SocketException.class)
                .redeliveryDelay("{{producer.retry.delay}}")
                .maximumRedeliveries("{{producer.retry.attempts}}")
                    .logRetryAttempted(true)
                    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
                    .logRetryStackTrace(false)
                .to(DIRECT_PRODUCER_ERROR)
                .handled(true)
            .end()
            .onException(ReadTimeoutException.class, NettyHttpOperationFailedException.class)
                .to(DIRECT_PRODUCER_ERROR)
                .handled(true)
            .end()

            .process(convertRequestCharset)
            .removeHeaders(headerFilter.getRequestHeadersToRemove(), headerFilter.getRequestHeadersToKeep())
            .bean(MessageInfoLogger.class, LOG_REQ_OUT_METHOD)
            .choice().when(exchangeProperty(ExchangeProperties.URL).contains("https://"))
                    .recipientList(simple(NETTY4_HTTPS_OUTGOING_TOD))
                    .endChoice()
                .otherwise()
                    .recipientList(simple(NETTY4_HTTP_TOD))
                    .endChoice()
            .end()
            .bean(MessageInfoLogger.class, LOG_RESP_IN_METHOD)
            .process(convertResponseCharset)
            .end();

        from(DIRECT_PRODUCER_ERROR)
            .process(handleProducerExceptionProcessor)
            .choice()
            .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isNotEqualTo("200"))
                .bean(MessageInfoLogger.class, LOG_ERROR_METHOD)
            .end()
            .process(convertResponseCharset)
            .removeHeaders(headerFilter.getResponseHeadersToRemove(), headerFilter.getResponseHeadersToKeep())
            .bean(MessageInfoLogger.class, LOG_RESP_OUT_METHOD)
            .end();
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what version of Apache Camel are you using and post the code for your route(s) as well?

Comment: What Camel version do you use? And yeah maybe we can do something along what you are doing out of the box and ignore the exception as it smells like that the exchange has timed out and are done already, but needs more investment.

Comment: <camel.version>2.24.0</camel.version>

Comment: Question was updated with rout.

Comment: I created a small project to show an error https://github.com/mtuliakova/ConnectionResetByPeer_Camel